# JTextArea - How to set text at a specified offset?

Tags: java, swing, offset, jtextarea, settext

I want to set some text at a specified offset in my `JTextArea`. Let's say I have already in my edit `"aaa bbb"` and I want to overwrite `"bbb"` with "house", how can I do that in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`replaceRange()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#replaceRange%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29)

> `public void replaceRange(String str,
>                            int start,
>                            int end)`
>
> Replaces text from the indicated start to end position with the new text specified. Does nothing if the model is null. Simply does a delete if the new string is null or empty.
>
> This method is thread safe, although most Swing methods are not. Please see Threads and Swing for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jigar, however I'm getting the following exception:

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification
 at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.writeLock(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JTextArea.replaceRange(Unknown Source)
 at MyTextArea$MyDocumentListener.insertUpdate(MyTextArea.java:75)
 at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(Unknown Source)

Comment: +1, this works too fine :-) Better than mine, in single line :-) @BoleGrat, seems like you doing it at the wrong place, inside `DocumentFilter` which is not the right place i guess, at this place, you can not make changes to the Document itself.

Comment: nIcE cOw: you are right, I will try to do something different. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take a look at three methods [setSelectionStart(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setSelectionStart%28int%29), [setSelectionEnd(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setSelectionEnd%28int%29) and [replaceSelection(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#replaceSelection%28java.lang.String%29).

Here is a small sample program to help your cause :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextAreaSelection
{
    private JTextField replaceTextField;
    private JTextField startIndexField;
    private JTextField endIndexField;

    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTextArea Selection");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);

        final JTextArea tarea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
        tarea.setText("aaa bbb");

        final JButton updateButton = new JButton("UPDATE TEXT");
        updateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                //tarea.setSelectionStart(4);
                //tarea.setSelectionEnd(7);
                //tarea.replaceSelection("house");
                int selection = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, getPanel());
                if (selection == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
                {
                    if (replaceTextField.getDocument().getLength() > 0
                        && startIndexField.getDocument().getLength() > 0
                        && endIndexField.getDocument().getLength() > 0)
                    {   
                        String text = replaceTextField.getText().trim();
                        int start = Integer.parseInt(startIndexField.getText().trim());
                        int end = Integer.parseInt(endIndexField.getText().trim());
                        tarea.replaceRange(text, start, end);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        contentPane.add(tarea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(updateButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.getContentPane().add(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getPanel()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 2, 2));

        JLabel replaceLabel = new JLabel("Enter new String : "
                                                , JLabel.CENTER);
        replaceTextField = new JTextField(10);

        JLabel startIndexLabel = new JLabel("Enter Start Index : "
                                                , JLabel.CENTER);
        startIndexField = new JTextField(10);   

        JLabel endIndexLabel = new JLabel("Enter End Index : ");
        endIndexField = new JTextField(10); 

        panel.add(replaceLabel);
        panel.add(replaceTextField);
        panel.add(startIndexLabel);
        panel.add(startIndexField);
        panel.add(endIndexLabel);
        panel.add(endIndexField);

        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new TextAreaSelection().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: nIcE cOw, ty for the suggestion but is occuring the same problem as before and, honestly, I don't want to make it using setSelection(). I prefer using the replaceString() or insert(). I continue getting the same exception in all the cases :(

Comment: See If i do it, it's working fine in this new edited answer, as adviced by @JigarJoshi

Comment: I am adding tarea.replaceRange("house", 4, 7); inside DocumentListener::insertUpdate() event. Simple stuff and it gives me this exception.

Comment: Yeah inside DocumentListener, you can not do that. Updation of the Document can not take place, inside `DocumentListener`. Since at that time it has a write lock on the Document. See this latest update. Let me check that too, from my side